# What is the typical timeframe it takes the European Parliament to regulate important software usage aspects?

Tags: regulation, technology, european-parliament

#### Context

According to [Euronews](https://www.euronews.com/next/2023/02/06/chatgpt-in-the-spotlight-as-the-eu-steps-up-calls-for-tougher-regulation-is-its-new-ai-act), at least one EU parliamentary is arguing for better regulation surrounding AI products:

> An EU official has said proposed rules regulating artificial
> intelligence (AI) will tackle concerns around the risks of products
> like ChatGPT.

The same article mentions AI Act, draft legislation [proposed in April 2021](https://www.sidley.com/en/insights/newsupdates/2022/12/proposal-for-eu-artificial-intelligence-act-passes-next-level).

> Under the EU draft rules, ChatGPT is considered a general-purpose AI
> system which can be used for multiple purposes, including high-risk
> ones such as the selection of candidates for jobs and credit scoring.

In the case of ChatGPT and similar systems, [things are pretty far from clear regarding data protection and privacy](https://www.information-age.com/chatgpt-vs-gdpr-what-ai-chatbots-mean-for-data-privacy-123501570/) and I guess that makes regulation even harder.

#### Question

How much it typically takes for such a regulation to be approved? The only example I know about is [GRPR which took more than four years to be adopted](https://www.wired.co.uk/article/what-is-gdpr-uk-eu-legislation-compliance-summary-fines-2018).

I am interested in a qualitative answer (e.g. 3-5 years).

Comment: I don't think that there is any such thing as "typical". It doesn't happen often enough for there to be a meaningful answer. A clear and obvious emergency situation could probably be done in weeks or months. Four years is certainly not an upper bound.

Comment: The Commission invited experts to a conference about modernizing privacy laws in 2009, made its first proposal in 2012, negotiated with the Parliament and Council for three years, which resulted in a joint proposal in 2015, it was adopted by the Council and the Parliament in 2016 and entered into force 20 days later, and became directly applicable to all member states in 2018. So, depending on how you count, the GDPR took 9 years, not 4.